# Network connection keeps failing on some networks [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: 20.04, network-manager

I have a strange issue regarding my network connection. On most networks there is no problem and everything works great, and then on some networks I cannot seem to load any pages or keep any connection stable. Also ssh connections on the terminal and other connections are unstable. The network says it is still connected, but apparently it is not.

My first thought was it could be a WiFi issue, but the problem remains when trying through a wired connection. Everytime I reconnect it works for a brief moment, but never long.

I have read through some other questions here and one StackOverflow, but none look like they describe the same issue.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be or had the same issue and found a fix for it?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Precision 5550, if any more details are needed please comment so I can provide them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated it, I also added that when reconnecting it works for a brief moment, but never long

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am currently not having the issue, but I now where to replicate it so I can try it out then. Will update the question with the logs